# Convert image into binary file in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, binaryfiles

I am new to react native and I am practicing converting images into binary files. I randomly downloaded the image from the internet. I am trying to convert images into binary files to upload to the server through API. The server takes input as a binary file. I have attached the code below. I searched on the internet but could not find the solution.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Button,
    Alert
} from 'react-native'


let imagePath = './src/image/macTest.jpeg'

const imageToBinary = (imagePath) => {
    //Alert.alert(imagePath)

// this function needs to convert image into the binary file
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.headerStyle}> Image </Text>

            <Image
                style={styles.imageStyle}
                source= {require('./src/image/macTest.jpeg')}
            />

            <Button 
                title="Binary Value"
                onPress={() => imageToBinary(imagePath)}
            />

            <View style= {styles.binaryStyle}>
               <Text>
               // binary value of the image
               </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    headerStyle:{
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 15
    },

    imageStyle:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 300,
        width: 450,
    },

    binaryStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        margin: 5
    }

})

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Expo there is `FileSystem`:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options

Example:

```
const img = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(photo.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Another alternative is `react-native-image-picker`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

Comment: In the above code, there is no `react-native-image-picker`. So, I am just trying to convert the image into a binary file. But actually, I am using both `react-native-image-picker` and `react-native-image-crop-picker` to select the image from the gallery and display it on the screen. So, now I want to upload the selected image to the server. I am actually using RN not expo. So, here is the code from `react-native-image-crop-picker` to select the picture so, what would be the next step to convert it into the binary file. I have tried every possible step that I can in past few days.

Comment: `
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});
`

If we have this as a code for selecting the image then how can we convert it into binary?